# Name for an ordered k-combination with repetition?

Tags: combinatorics, terminology

This is a terminology question.

Suppose I pull elements from a set, with no restrictions on repetition, to create an ordered list of k elements. I believe I'm creating an "ordered k-combination with repetition", but I have a hunch there's a better term for this. If so, what is it?

To illustrate my question with an example, what can I call these lists, relative to the set {A,B,C}?
AA
AB
AC
BA
BB
BC
CA
CB
CC

Comment: These are variations with repetition.

Comment: They are [permutations with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_with_repetition), $k$-tuples, or words.

Comment: Would I be using the word "tuple" properly if I say "(A,A), (A,B), (A,C), (B,A), (B,B), (B,C), (C,A), (C,B), and (C,C) are the 2-tuples of {A,B,C}"?

Answer (score 3):

Where I live (in the Balkans), the common terminology for these would be "variations with repetition", though wikipedia says this is apparently an archaic term, and offers "k-tuple" instead.

According to the other comment on your question, it seems somewhere they are also called "permutations with repetition" though as I've learned, these correspond to what's on the same wikipedia page called "permutations of multisets".

Comment: A permutation of a multiset means that you are specifying some number of $A$'s, some number of $B$'s and so on. So if your multiset is $\{A,A,B\}$ then the permutations are $AAB, ABA, BAA$ but not $ABB$ because that has the wrong number of $A$'s and $B$'s.

Comment: Yes, true, I'm just giving the terminology we used in my class for it.